# Shell script if statement [: unexpected operator

Tags: linux, shell, debian, sh

I am trying to create a very simple shell script which detects if it's being run as `root`. For some reason, the code below produces a `Error: [: stackunderflow: unexpected operator` on line 6, I have no idea why? I have this working on a bash script but for portability and some education, I wanted to do this with a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
##
# Check for root launch
#
set -e
USER="$(id -un 2>/dev/null || true)"
if [ "$USER" == 'root' ]; then
    echo "You must be a root user"
    exit 1
else
    echo 'Not root!'
    exit 0
fi
```

This is being run as `./check.sh` from a Debian Jessie amd64 desktop.

Comment: replace "==" with "="

Comment: Thanks for that :)

Comment: Side note: you're overriding the [`USER` environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08). That's why it is highly recommended to not use upper case variable names!

Comment: Aaaah, thanks for that. I will adjust the script accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you have this tagged as bash, and it's bourne.  As sigmalha pointed out, you are using the wrong operator.  Use = instead of ==.

In addition, you are failing (exit 1) on a success, and succeeding (exit 0) on your failure.

Comment: Thank you, apologies.. I guess I'm still learning.

Comment: no prob, we were all beginners once